# How to use ISNULL and HASHBYTES in the same query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `ISNULL` command in a SQL Server `UPDATE` procedure and I am using password hashbyte

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Users]
    (@Id INT,
     @StaffName NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
     @Email NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
     @UserName VARCHAR(40),
     @Password VARCHAR(50),
     @Phoneno NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
     @Admin CHAR(3) NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Users 
    SET StaffName = ISNULL(StaffName, @StaffName),
        Email = ISNULL(Email, @Email),
        UserName = ISNULL(UserName, @UserName),
        PasswordHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Password),
        Phoneno = ISNULL(Phoneno, @Phoneno),
        [IsAdmin] = ISNULL(IsAdmin, @Admin)
    WHERE Id = @Id
END
```

How can I use `hashbytes` and use `isnull` on the `passwordhash` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I guess this right, but from the pattern of your `UPDATE` you might want

```
...
passwordhash = isnull(password, hashbytes('SHA2_512', @Password)),
...
```

i.e. if the `passwordhash` is null replace it with the hash of the password in the `@password` variable.

Answer (score 0):

convert to varbinary

```
 isnull( HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Password),convert (varbinary,'') )
```

Try this

```
 alter procedure [dbo].[Update_Users]
(
@Id int ,
@StaffName nvarchar(50)   ,
@Email nvarchar(100)  ,
@UserName varchar(40),
@Password varchar(50),
@Phoneno nvarchar(50)  ,
@Admin char(3)   
)
as
 begin
 Update Users 
 Set StaffName=ISnull(StaffName,@StaffName),
  Email=ISnull(Email,@Email),
  UserName=Isnull(UserName,@UserName),
  PasswordHash =  isnull( HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Password),convert (varbinary,'') ),
  Phoneno=Isnull(Phoneno,@Phoneno),
  [IsAdmin]=Isnull(IsAdmin,@Admin)
  where Id=@Id
end
```